# How can I make a custom conversion from an object to a dict?

Tags: python

I have a Python class that stores some fields and has some properties, like

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  @property
  def z(self):
    return self.x+1
```

What changes do I need to make to the class so that I can do

```
>>> a = A(1,5)
>>> dict(a)
{'y':5, 'z':2}
```

where I specify that I want to return `y` and `z`? I can't just use `a.__dict__` because it would contain `x` but not `z`. I would like to be able to specify anything that can be accessed with `__getattribute__`.

Comment: Could you not rewrite was a.__dict__ does?

Comment: `a.__dict__` is a pretty integral part of how python classes store fields, and I am very reluctant to mess with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add an `__iter__()` method to your class that returns an iterator of the object's items as key-value pairs. Then you can pass your object instance directly to the `dict()` constructor, as it accepts a sequence of key-value pairs.

```
def __iter__(self):
    for key in "y", "z":
        yield key, getattr(self, key)
```

If you want this to be a little more flexible, and allow the list of attributes to be easily overridden on subclasses (or programmatically) you could store the key list as an attribute of your class:

```
_dictkeys = "y", "z"

def __iter__(self):
    for key in self._dictkeys:
        yield key, getattr(self, key)
```

If you want the dictionary to contain all attributes (including those inherited from parent classes) try:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for key in dir(self):
        if not key.startswith("_"):
            value = getattr(self, key)
            if not callable(value):
                yield key, value
```

This excludes members that start with "_" and also callable objects (e.g. classes and functions).

Comment: Great, the second code block is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I think a reasonable approach to this problem would be to create an `asdict` method. When you say you want to specify which keys you want the dict to contain, I assume you're happy with that information being passed when the method is called. If that's not what you mean, let me know. (This incorporates [kindall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915532/how-can-i-make-a-custom-conversion-from-an-object-to-a-dict/10915645#comment14235676_10915645)'s excellent suggestion.)

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self.x+1

    def asdict(self, *keys):
        if not keys:
            keys = ['y', 'z']
        return dict((key, getattr(self, key)) for key in keys)
```

Tested:

```
>>> A(1, 2).asdict('x', 'y')
{'y': 2, 'x': 1}
>>> A(1, 2).asdict()
{'y': 2, 'z': 2}
```

Comment: I like this because it lets you specify the keys on the fly. You might want to have a default list, though.

Comment: This is pretty similar to what I already have, but my particular interest was in using the `dict` builtin.

Comment: Handy shortcut for supplying default values for containers: `keys = keys or ['y', 'z']`

Answer (score 0):

A naive way to solve this would be the following. It might not be enough for your needs but I am just pointing it out in case you've missed it.

```
>>> dict(y=a.y, z=a.z)
>>> {'y': 5, 'z': 2}
```